# I'm making a personality quiz and I need one question to be random

Tags: javascript, list

Hi so I'm making a personality quiz and I just need the 5th question to be random I did the following but it doesn't output anything when I get to question 5 where the random question from the list should be there is no text output.

```
                <form>
                    <div id="randomDisplay" text-center></div>
                    <input data-endingsentence="" onclick="setAnswerButton()" type="radio">Ja
                    <input data-endingsentence="" name="rq" onclick="setAnswerButton()" type="radio">Nee
                </form>
                <script>
                    var questions = [
                        'Jy verkies ’n bosveldvakansie bo ’n seewegbreek.'
                        'Wanneer jy verslaap het, sal jy eerder laat wees vir ’n afspraak as om nie ontbyt te eet nie.'
                        'As jy koeldrank by ŉ restaurant bestel, drink jy dit met ŉ strooitjie.'
                        'As jy ŉ hemp aantrek, trek jy eerste die linkermou aan.'
                        'Wanneer jy ’n boek lees, lees jy soms die einde voor die boek klaar is.'
                        'Wanneer jy ’n troeteldier aanskaf, sal jy eerder ’n kat as ’n hond kies.'
                        'Jy hou meer van somer as van winter.'
                        'As jy klaar tande geborsel het, spoeg jy die tandepasta uit sonder om jou mond met water uit te spoel.'
                        'Wanneer jy steak in ’n restaurant bestel, sal jy vra dat dit halfgaar voorberei word.'
                        'Jy gooi tamatiesous oor jou slaptjips.'
                        'Jy sal eerder ŉ legkaart bou as om 30 Seconds saam met jou vriende te speel.'
                    ]

                    function newQuestion() {
                        var randomQuestions = Math.floor(Math.random() *(randomQuestions.length));
                        document.getElementById('randomDisplay').innerHTML = randomQuestions[questions];
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: `randomQuestion[newQuestion]` ... newQuestion is the function ... `randomQuestion` is the list of random questions ... but, in `newQuestion` it's a number! - you are a) using the wrong variable, and b) have a name clash therefore can't access the list of random questions outside of that function ... solution: use unique (and correct) variable names

Comment: Where do you call `newQuestion()`?

Comment: Did you also call the ˋfunction newQuestion()ˋ somewhere? If not, add ˋnewQuestion();ˋ as last line of the script.

Comment: Thanks for the help I see I wrote the wrong variable so they are clashing

Comment: changed the variable names but still no output should I use ```return newQuestion``` @PaulH

Comment: post the rest of your code that defines and uses those variables and functions.

Comment: that is the part of the code that uses the functions and variables at the top is where I would like to display the random question in the 
```<form>
      <div id="randomDisplay" text-center></div>
      <input data-endingsentence="" onclick="setAnswerButton()" type="radio">Ja
      <input data-endingsentence="" name="rq" onclick="setAnswerButton()"                   type="radio">Nee
 </form>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code.
This should help you (Please compare it side by side to get the idea of what was wrong in your code).
Note: you have not defined `setAnswerButton` (or at least not mentioned it in the question, so please do make sure it is implemented)

```html
<form>
    <div id="randomDisplay" style="text-align:center"></div>
    <input data-endingsentence="" onclick="setAnswerButton()" type="radio">Ja
    <input data-endingsentence="" name="rq" onclick="setAnswerButton()" type="radio">Nee
</form>
<script>
    (function () {
        var questions = [
            "Test question1",
            "Test question2",
            "Test question3",
            "Test question4",
            "Test question5"
        ]

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
        document.getElementById('randomDisplay').innerText = questions[randomIndex];
    })();
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you put it in a function? Thanks. If it is to declare local variables and avoid name conflicts, this can be done with 'let' now.

Comment: @PaulH Hey, if you look closely the function is called right away using (function...)().
It is written that way to mimic "document.ready" from JQuery.

Comment: @"Saud Qureshi" Yes, it is called immediatly and yes, it is like document.ready, but why should that be a reason? What is the function? Wouldn't it be more clear and readable if removed?

Comment: @PaulH Since I generally write multiple functions in script I prefer to keep a self invoking function that bootstraps and starts the application. I guess it's there in my muscle memory now.